# web server + Chrome v40 + font awesome does not work

Tags: css, google-chrome, nginx, mime-types, font-awesome

I bought a theme from themeforest that uses font-awesome and simple-line-icons

When I opened the static html files using Chrome, it works perfectly.

I refactor the html so that it works with my php app, and I serve the php files using nginx and php-fpm.

The icons show up as squares in Chrome.

I look at the same url in Safari. The icons are okay.

I then opened up /etc/nginx/mime.types and added

```
font/ttf                      ttf;
font/opentype                 otf;
application/font-woff         woff;
application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;
```

right at the bottom just before the curly brace `}`.

I also commented out the original `eot` value in the `mime.types`.

Restarted the nginx.

The same issue persists.

Also tried clearing browser caches. Same issue persists.

When I change to use cdn for the font-awesome, the font-awesome icons work perfectly.

Unfortunately there is no cdn for simple-line-icons.

In summary,

- open static files using Chrome NOT using cdn == okay
- open php files served by nginx using Safari without altering the mime.types NOT using cdn == okay
- open php files served by nginx using Safari after altering the mime.types NOT using cdn == okay
- open php files served by nginx using Chrome after using cdn == okay
- open php files served by nginx using Chrome without altering the mime.types NOT using cdn == NOT okay
- open php files served by nginx using Chrome after altering the mime.types NOT using cdn == NOT okay

I am using Chrome v40 on macbook pro. Nginx is on ubuntu 14.04 via a VM.

I am stumped. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating the font files using [Font Squirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) using TTF file you have and replace the existing one in the theme.

Comment: May I ask why I should do that?

Comment: the font that came with the theme might be corrupt/ broken.

Comment: if it works with Safari under all circumstances, why should the font be broken?

Comment: did you try with any other browser?

Each browser uses different font file extension for rendering characters i.e. ttf, otf, etc.